# sed command does not replace entire string

Tags: string, bash, sed

My string is as follows:

```
[ -f /sbin/runuser ] && eval '/sbin/runuser - root -c "/etc/init.d/vcs -start"' || /bin/su - root -c "/etc/init.d/vcs -start"
```

After replacement of the string i require an output as follows:

```
[ -f /sbin/runuser ] && eval '/sbin/runuser - myuser -c "/etc/init.d/vcs -start"' || /bin/su - root -c "/etc/init.d/vcs -start"
```

With help of sed command i am trying to replace the same, but its just replacing half of the string. I have used the following command:

```
sed s@"/sbin/runuser .* -c \"${RC_VCS}"@"/sbin/runuser - $myuser -c \"${RC_VCS}"@g
```

whereas `${RC_VCS}` is `/etc/init.d/vcs` and `$myuser` is `dummy`

My output for the same comes as follows:

```
[ -f /sbin/runuser ] && eval '/sbin/runuser - dummy -c "/etc/init.d/vcs -start"
```

Can anyone please help me as why the sed command is just taking half of the string during replacement and how i can replace the word in that string?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
sed -E 's#(/sbin/runuser - )[^ ]+#\1runuser#' file.txt
```

it will replace only the instance of string `root` with `myuser` when the string `root` is preceded by `/sbin/runuser -`.